# AWS Elasticache/Redis Access Outside of VPC?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-vpc, amazon-elasticache

I have a lambda I want to run outside of my VPC to avoid NAT costs. The only service it needs to access within the VPC is an Elasticache instance. I can't create a VPC Endpoint between my lambda and Elasticache, so I'm not sure how I can connect to it without putting my lambda within the VPC and going through NAT.

How can I connect to a redis instance outside of the VPC? Bastion server?

Comment: Why do you need NAT to connect to your EC if you put your lambda in a VPC?

Comment: @Marcin I want to run the lambda outside of the VPC to avoid NAT. Because EC must live inside the VPC, I don't know how to connect my lambda to EC without also putting the lambda in the VPC

Comment: Putting it in a VPC is the correct way of doing this. You don't need NAT for your lambda to interact with EC in a VPC.

Comment: @Marcin The NAT cost isn't because of the connection to EC... The lambda is accessing out-of-vpc resources and it's costing $4.5k/mo. I could simply move it outside of the VPC if it didn't need a connection to EC.

Comment: If you try to access EC over the internet through some bastion you will introduce a considerable delay. Have you considered any alternatives to NAT gateway? Maybe running tiny NAT instance (not gateway) would be better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think in your cases there are 3 possible solutions:

1. Like one of the folks said above, deploy our own NAT instance on EC2 instead of using AWS NAT Gateway which can be quite expensive. But of coz you will need to setup / maintain and scale the NAT instance yourself.
2. Deploy a proxy in EC2 in public subnet of the VPC, said deploy a Nginx and set proxy_pass to the ElastiCache cluster in the VPC. In this way your lambda outside VPC can call the Nginx Elastic IP for ElastiCache requests. But please consider to put Network LB in front of an auto scaling group of Nginx EC2 for resiliency. Main concern in  this solution is security, your nginx security group need to open 0.0.0.0/0 for EC access (as lambda outside VPC come with different public IPs and no security group itself), ensure you enable encryption in transit and access control using AUTH or RBAC in Redis (if your EC is redis for example)
3. Both 1 and 2 involve building a EC2 instance yourself which increase maintenance burden. I think the best solution is to breakdown your Lambda function into two functions, one handle the EC call (Lambda A) and the other handle the internet API call (Lambda B), put Lambda A in VPC while keep Lambda B outside VPC, and simply use invoke API to call Lambda B from A or vice versa. This should be the best solution but involves more work in coding perspective.

Comment: It's a bummer but we did end up going with #3. It seemed like the least worst solution. In the future I hope AWS provides some kind of public EC access or allow public subnet lambdas to access the internet.

Answer (score 0):

Problem with two lambda functions is the extra delay when invoking another lambda function just for making a cache request. Because lambda invoke takes at least an extra 10-20ms, which is much longer than what redis request would take.

Comment: Your answer seems be more a comment than an actual solution. Please provide more details related to specific question.